# AngularJS $timeout function not executing in my Jasmine specs

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to test my AngularJS controller with Jasmine, using Karma. But a `$timeout` which works well in real-life, crashes my tests.

Controller:

```
var Ctrl = function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.doStuff = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.stuffDone = true;
    }, 250);
  };
};
```

Jasmine it block (where `$scope` and controller have been properly initialized):

```
it('should do stuff', function() {
  runs(function() {
    $scope.doStuff();
  });
  waitsFor(function() { 
    return $scope.stuffDone; 
  }, 'Stuff should be done', 750);
  runs(function() {
    expect($scope.stuffDone).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

When I run my app in browser, `$timeout` function will be executed and `$scope.stuffDone` will be true. But in my tests, `$timeout` does nothing, the function is never executed and Jasmine reports error after timing out 750 ms. What could possibly be wrong here?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

According to the Angular JS documentation for [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout), you can use `$timeout.flush()` to synchronously flush the queue of deferred functions.

Try updating your test to this:

```
it('should do stuff', function() {
  expect($scope.stuffDone).toBeFalsy();
  $scope.doStuff();
  expect($scope.stuffDone).toBeFalsy();
  $timeout.flush();
  expect($scope.stuffDone).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Here is a [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/exO5AESD6st4VaAVcfRH/preview) showing both your original test failing and the new test passing.

Comment: Thanks. Should've RTFM. It seems that in Jasmine tests ngMocks module is loaded and the mocked $timeout actually never calls window.setTimeout - am I correct?

Comment: Correct, take a look at the code on Github [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L648) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L1491).

Comment: So those Github links were referring to master and are no longer useful.  Here are the same links against that version for those that are curious: [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.1.5/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L648) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.1.5/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L1466)

Comment: This helps. But i had to call done() in the end to mark end of test case. Otherwise jasmine waits for 5sec(default) and fails as done() is not called. Hope this helps

Answer (score 10):

As noted in one of the comments, Jasmine `setTimeout` mock is not being used because angular's JS mock `$timeout` service is used instead. Personally, I'd rather use Jasmine's because its mocking method lets me test the length of the timeout. You can effectively circumvent it with a simple provider in your unit test:

```
module(function($provide) {
  $provide.constant('$timeout', setTimeout);
});
```

Note: if you go this route, be sure to call `$scope.apply()` after jasmine.Clock.tick.

Comment: How do I reverse it back to the angular timeout mock, as I have other tests where I don't want to use jasmine mock?

Comment: Is it possible to switch back to using timeout.flush(1000) in any of those tests? It seems that using jasmine.clock().tick(1000) isn't a perfect substitute in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

As  `$timeout` is just a wrapper for `window.setTimeout`, you can use jasmines `Clock.useMock()` which mocks the `window.setTimeout`

```
  beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.Clock.useMock();
  });

  it('should do stuff', function() {
    $scope.doStuff();
    jasmine.Clock.tick(251);
    expect($scope.stuffDone).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: This is for the Jasmine 1.x API. For Jasmine 2.x you would run `jasmine.clock().install()` in your `beforeEach`, `jasmine.clock().uninstall()` in your `afterEach` and `jasmine.clock().tick(251)` in your `it` function.