# Unit testing controller when $timeout is called within an init() function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, chutzpah

I am trying to run a jasmine test in visual studios using chutzpah/test explorer.

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
function ctrl($scope, $timeout, resolvedData) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.data;
  init();

  function init() {
    if(resolvedData.length > 0) {
      $timeout(function() {
        vm.data = resolvedData;
      }, 0);
    };
  };
}
```

My test file looks like this:

```
describe('ctrl', function() {
  var ctrl,
      resolvedData,
      $controller,
      $timeout,
      $scope;
  var mockResolvedData = [{}, {}, {}];

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('app');
    inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$timeout_) {
      $scope = _$rootScope.$new();
      $controller = _$controller_;
      $timeout = _$timeout_;
      resolvedData = mockResolvedData;
      ctrl = $controller('ctrl', {$scope: $scope, resolvedData: resolvedData, $timeout: $timeout})
    })
  })

  it('should set data when the controller loads', function() {
    $timeout.flush();
    expect(ctrl.data).toEqual(mockResolvedData);
  })
})
```

When I add the $timeout.flush(), I get this error:

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Taking out the $timeout.flush() gives me this error:

> Expected undefined to equal [ {  }, {  }, {  } ].

Adding $scope.$apply() before the expect (instead of $timeout.flush()) gives me this:

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Is there something else that I am missing?  I want to test that vm.data gets set when the controller loads after the function from $timeout is called but no luck.

**EDIT 1:**
I created a plunker and it's working fine in their.  I'm stumped.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ae28AyjKwCTen1nHKZAo?p=preview

**EDIT 2:**
I replaced $timeout.flush() with $timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks() like this:

```
it('should do set data when the controller loads', function() {
  $timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks();
  expect(ctrl.data)toEqual(mockResolvedData);
})
```

And now I have this error:

> Error: Deferred tasks to flush (2): {id: 0, time: 0}, {id: 1, time: 0}

So we can clearly see that there are tasks to be flushed but when I flush them, I get that digest error.

Comment: i've read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418716/unit-testing-angular-service-that-uses-timeout-with-jasmines-mock-clock

and this: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350492/angularjs-timeout-function-not-executing-in-my-jasmine-specs

but no luck

Comment: Thats a wierd error but with the code you have you should ideally get no deferred tasks to be flushed or something like that because your time out will never run in the controller due to typo @ `if(resolvedData.lenth > 0) {` check the spelling of `length`

Comment: i apologize for spelling it wrong here.  it is spelled correctly in my code.

Comment: Is it only blowing up in PhantomJS?  It's also not clear to my why you're putting a timeout in your controller.  what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yep, it's only messing up in PhantomJS.  I have a time out in my controller because I have pre-resolved data that I want to animate.  The data will only animate (from ng-repeat) when I set a timeout.  The strange thing is I setup another identical controller spec to get tested in visual studios but no issues there.

Comment: Jason, here is a plunker demonstrating what I mean with the animations.  Without the $timeout and by setting the resolved data immediately, the animations don't trigger.  Once the controller loads, we wait before we populate the data for ng-repeat, then the animation works.
http://plnkr.co/edit/MQdKiaQf4MrFHrBnJdIV?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when calling $timeout with a callback function. When omitting this function, it did work. For your controller this would mean:

```
$timeout(vm.data = resolvedData, 0);
```

I know this is a less favoutive solution, but it works in both the controller and the test.